# Get select tag value in tables with dynamic rows in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to set the value of select tag in VM data.

```
<table id="vm" v-cloak>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th><th>Operation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) in rowData">
      <td>
        <select v-model="selected" @change="changeDate($event)">
          <option v-for="sItem in selectItems" :value="sItem.val">{{sItem.lbl}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="addRow(i)">+</button>
        <button @click="removeRow(i)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My script

```
// Select tag items
const SELECT_ITEMS = [
  {val:"1", lbl:"Val1"},
  {val:"2", lbl:"Val2"},
  {val:"3", lbl:"Val3"}
];

// my vm
new Vue({
  el: "#vm",
  data:{
    rowData:[{val:"1"},{val:"2"}],
    selected : '',
    selectItems : SELECT_ITEMS
  },
  methods:{
    // add new row
    addRow(i){
      let row = {
        val : this.selected,
      };
      this.rowData.splice(i, 0, row);
      this.val = '';
    },
    // remove current row
    removeRow(i){
      this.rowData.splice(i,1);
    },
    changeDate(e){
      // I want to set a value to item in rowData.
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/yanchi4425/pen/oOQwLP?editors=1111)

I do not know how to set the selected data to the data of the current row of rowData.

And, changing one changes all items.

And, I want to add selected attribute at loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly use the `rowData` in `v-model`?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMREPJ?editors=1111):

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in rowData">
  <td>
    <select v-model="rowData[i].val" @change="changeDate($event)">
      <option v-for="sItem in selectItems" :value="sItem.val">{{sItem.lbl}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button @click="addRow(i)">+</button>
    <button @click="removeRow(i)">-</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks.

Where is the definition of "selected" in line 22?
If,  multiple select tags in multiple columns, how do you use it?

Comment: There's no need for `selected` data. You can directly manipulate the `rowData[i].val` in `v-model`. I have updated my answer with some description.

Answer (score 0):

Your select tags are all bound to the same variable. If you make the model a property of the rowData item, then you will get unique values per row:

change: `v-model="selected"`
to:     `v-model="item.value"`

pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPJqqR?editors=0001

new template:

```
<table id="vm" v-cloak>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th><th>Operation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) in rowData" :key="i">
      <td>
        <select v-model="item.value" @change="changeDate($event)">
          <option v-for="sItem in selectItems" :value="sItem.val">{{sItem.lbl}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="addRow(i)">+</button>
        <button @click="removeRow(i)">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example `item.value` is just an option, you can use whatever property name you prefer such as `item.rowName`. It just has to be a property of the item object created by rowData.